# Books not appearing in iBooks on iPad

Tags: books

I have several books in my iBooks app on my iPad, but when I'm without wifi, ibooks doesn't even show the books are sitting in my library, why?

Answer (score 1):

If the books don't show up when offline that means that they have not actually been downloaded to your iPad. You should see a little cloud icon in the corner of the book icon to say that it's on the cloud rather than the device.